# ibm db2 create index in tablespace does not work

Tags: db2

I created a database on db2 11.5, then tablespace, then create a table. Everything okay so far.
However, when i tried to create index in the newly created TABLESPACE, it complains syntax error:

```
CREATE INDEX SCH.TBL_CAT_ERR_NIX01 ON SCH.TBL_CAT_ERR (CAT_NO ASC, CAT_ERR_ID ASC) in TBS_CAT_SINDEX;
```

with error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0109N  The statement or command was not processed because the following
clause is not supported in the context where it is used: "IN".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

i tried these 2 but still they don't work, complaining the "PARTITION" clause is not supported

```
CREATE INDEX SCH.TBL_CAT_ERR_NIX01 ON SCH.TBL_CAT_ERR (CAT_NO ASC, CAT_ERR_ID ASC) partitioned in TBS_CAT_SINDEX;

CREATE INDEX SCH.TBL_CAT_ERR_NIX01 ON SCH.TBL_CAT_ERR (CAT_NO ASC, CAT_ERR_ID ASC) not partitioned in TBS_CAT_SINDEX;
```

Could you help me pointing out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your `create table` statement, you can optionally specify the `index in` clause at that time to allow indexes to use a specific tablespace that you pre-created. Additional capabilities are available for PARTITIONED tables.

The key detail you omitted from your question was whether or not your table is itself partitioned.

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-index) for `create index`  states that the `IN tablespapace-name`  clause can **only** be specified or a nonpartitioned index on a partitioned table.  So if your table is not itself partitioned then you cannot use this IN clause when creating an index, and you should consider using the `create table` statement to identify an index tablespace for that table instead.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. The table itself is not partitioned and already created with tablespace for data and tablespace for index.